# SelectedIndex is always 0 in dropdownlist(asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am retrieving data from table **`Technology`** in dropdownlist **`ddlTechnology`** .

I have `TechnologyId` as primary key in the table and values are 1,2,3,4

Now as per the technology,i have to add questions in question bank. but when i select any item in dropdownlist, my **`SelectedIndex`** is always 0.

i want **`TechnologyId`** from dropdownlist.

i have tried following code but its not working

```
using (dbDataContext dt = new dbDataContext())
        {
            var qry = from i in dt.Technologies
                      select i;

            ddlTechnology.DataSource = qry;
            ddlTechnology.DataValueField = "TechnologyId";
            ddlTechnology.DataTextField = "TechnologyName";
            ddlTechnology.DataBind();
            ddlTechnology.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Technology", ""));
        }
```

Add button to add question according to selected technology.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (dbDataContext dt = new dbDataContext())
    {
        Question objQtn = new Question();
        objQtn.Question1 = txtQuestion.Text;
        objQtn.Option1 = txtOption1.Text;
        objQtn.Option2 = txtOption2.Text;
        objQtn.Option3 = txtOption3.Text;
        objQtn.Answer = txtAnswer.Text;
        // below here selectedIndex is always zero..
        objQtn.TechnologyId = ddlTechnology.SelectedIndex;
        dt.Questions.InsertOnSubmit(objQtn);
        dt.SubmitChanges();
        txtAnswer.Text = "";
        txtOption1.Text = "";
        txtOption2.Text = "";
        txtOption3.Text = "";
        txtQuestion.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your page load please

Comment: Try using SelectedValue instead...

Comment: first code is in page_load

Comment: No. not in !IsPostback

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Reason1:**

Seems like you are binding dropdownlist on every postback. If that is a problem then keeping your load code in !IsPostBack shou work.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   using (dbDataContext dt = new dbDataContext())
        {
            var qry = from i in dt.Technologies
                      select i;

            ddlTechnology.DataSource = qry;
            ddlTechnology.DataValueField = "TechnologyId";
            ddlTechnology.DataTextField = "TechnologyName";
            ddlTechnology.DataBind();
            ddlTechnology.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Technology", ""));
        }
}
```

**Reason 2:**

In some cases if programmer disables `ViewState` property of any control/page then also control looses it's value on postback.

Answer (score 1):

Need to bind dropdown list in the below event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    // Bind your dropdown list
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code for ref. hope it will help you:
*(objQtn.TechnologyId = ddlTechnology.SelectedIndex;)*
 one of these two is of string type check once.

**Index.aspx**

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCloth" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button  runat="server" ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

**Index.aspx.cs**

```
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
         if (!Page.IsPostBack)
         {


            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name") });
            dt1.Rows.Add(1, "Shirt");
            dt1.Rows.Add(2, "Jeans");

            ddlCloth.DataSource = dt1;
            ddlCloth.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlCloth.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlCloth.DataBind();
        }


    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCloth.SelectedItem.Value);
        string text = Convert.ToString(ddlCloth.SelectedItem.Text);
        int index=Convert.ToInt32(ddlCloth.SelectedIndex);
    }
```